# What is the best way to check (and repair) hard drive for bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive

I used the following utilities to check my ext4 partitions:

1. fsck
2. badblocks

Google and SO also suggest smartctl. I'm just wondering what are the differences between all those tools and which one is better.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to repair bad sectors. They are automatically marked as unusable, without user intervention.

To find out what various programs do, see the man pages, for example:

[man badblocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/badblocks.8.html)

[man fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/fsck.8.html)

[man smartctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/smartctl.8.html)

You don't have to read everything, just the description.