# any big file download results in file error

Tags: downloads

My problem is that whenever I try downloading a big file **(100MB or more)**, it always gets completed but file is corrupted. I have been observing this when downloading Eclipse IDE. I tried many Eclipse versions, Scala IDE, but all result in the same error.

Is there something wrong with my Internet connection or my Hard Drive?

How to diagnose and fix this problem?

**Update **

i tried using another computer to download the same file on the same internet connection. the file download is successful. so it means something wrong in my harddisk only. i checked the Disk 'palimpsest' report and does show many "read errors" and many "Seek Errors" , many "hardware ECC recovered" . But the "Uncorrectable Sector Count" is 0. Does that mean my disk is a problem but it is a recoverable error? what can be done to recover from these errors?

**Update 2**

i tried attaching my phone as a USB device and downloaded the file in it. the file was downloaded  using `wget -c` command. The same error occured, i.e. extracting the .tar.gz file failed as there was a CRC error
that means Harddisk is OK, and internet connection is OK (see Update 1) ,  but there is something wrong in the OS? many times i am not even able to apply all updates as the updates also fail for the same reason "Hash Sum Mismatch"
plz help!!

Comment: Sometimes it happens due to internet connection. Better use any download manager like `flareGet`to download big files.

Comment: nope, i just now tried with `flareGet` also, but same kind of error. file cannot be opened. this is the file i am trying to download http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide-pack/3.0.2.vfinal-210-20131028/scala-SDK-3.0.2-vfinal-2.10-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: i get the error:tar: Skipping to next header

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error

gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: anyone? help please

Comment: @weima is there enough space in the drive, try downloading using chrome or other browser

Comment: yes, there is enough space in the drive. i downloaded using chrome and flareGet, both ways result in the same error

Comment: mostly i get this error while downloading eclipse package. downloading any eclipse version fails. now i found even downloading scala IDE fails. plz help

Comment: @weima - How are you extracting the file? It might not be the file that is faulty but the extractor?

Comment: the file is a .tar.gz file and i use tar -zxvf <file>

Comment: Can you list the content tar -t <file>?

Comment: have you tried downloading the file with `wget` by copying the link location of the file??

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? Are you using a wired connection or a wireless connection? Please edit your question with what router you are using.

Comment: You really need to provide more information. Also, are you using some kind of antivirus software on the system that is unable to complete large downloads? I know there are some antivirus softwares that cause that occasionally.

Comment: no antivirus software. i am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429501/any-big-file-download-results-in-file-error#comment563267_433364) him to check md5sum of the downloaded 100 MB file. This [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429501/any-big-file-download-results-in-file-error#comment563925_433364) clearly shows that his file was corrupted or may be chance of bit loss while downloading that file using a specific download manager(flareget).

So try to download that 100 MB file using different download manager.So see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/what-download-managers-are-available-for-ubuntu) question for the available download managers in Ubuntu which allows you to pause,resume while downloading.

Comment: gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: did you login into root account?

Comment: there is enough space in the partition  /dev/sda4       611G  225G  355G  39% /data

Comment: try `tar -xf /path/filename.tar.gz` command.

Comment: it is a .gz file, why remove z option?

Comment: i tried same error

Comment: did you check the md5sum of the download tar.gz file?

Comment: ok, i am also trying to do same, trying to find checksum from the site for the file i downloaded

Comment: Why do you login to the `root` account using `sudo su`? Can't you achieve the same using `sudo tar <whatever>`?

Comment: hi @AvinashRaj i got the sha1sum from the site. it is 3b22333939c745257847a5173f288571b7f8f432 but after downloading today i get 76afc0bf2c2cb2c15b558032e24d0381c487a0ae i dont know what is wrong

Comment: md5sum error.You have to redownload it.Try a different download manager.

Comment: i tried using another computer to download the same file on the same internet connection. the file download is successful. so it means something wrong in my harddisk only. i checked the Disk 'palimpsest' report and does show many "read errors" and many "Seek Errors" , many "hardware ECC recovered" . But the "Uncorrectable Sector Count" is 0. Does that mean my disk is a problem but it is a recoverable error? what can be done to recover from these errors?

Comment: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299483/how-to-clear-bad-sectors-in-hard-disk-using-ubuntu) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104070/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-and-repair-hard-drive-for-bad-sectors) to check for bad sectors on your disk.

Comment: well the problem is not solved yet. but still i thank @AvinashRaj for the help he provided

Answer (score 2):

Try to download the large file from terminal using wget

Example: `$ wget http://www.openss7.org/repos/tarballs/strx25-0.9.2.1.tar.bz2`

This will show you the progress and whether it got interrupted.

If got interrupted; you may resume the download again by adding `-c` switch as in the following

Example : `$ wget -c http://www.openss7.org/repos/tarballs/strx25-0.9.2.1.tar.bz2`

Source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/

Answer (score 1):

### It's a flareget bug

I have been using flareget for months now.It was working properly for some time, but nowadays, after an update or something, **flareget corrupts every file**.For now, using **mozilla** or **any other browser** is your best choice.

The `invalid commpressed data` error should not appear when you try downloading via browser.If it still does, use `wget` to download the file using command

```
wget -c <link>
```

You can use the following command to decompress the file

```
gzip -d /path/to/file
```

If error occurs, use `force` option

```
gzip -df /path/to/file
```

For extra guarranty, you may first want to check the integrity of file using

```
gzip -t /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pointing the download to another external static memory device like a USB flash drive or maybe even your cellphones SD card. If the download completely loads into the external memory device, then you may want to evaluate your local hardware for inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

What are the facts so far on this issue?

1. This happens only on big files (You tested this on other files?)
2. The CRC check fails
3. Download resumes are not helping either.

I am wondering if you don't have some cache manager or proxy or policy that writes to your open download...

You can try to spot differences using if you can get your hand on the original:

```
hexdump -C  scala-SDK-3.0.2-vfinal-2.10-linux.gtk.x86_64.tar.gz | head -n20
```

Have you tried doing the download via an independent internet connection?

Good luck!